# searching a jumbled string in a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, search

I am using .NET2.0
I want to search a jumbled string within a list of strings

```
string[] wordList = new string[] { "java", "csharp", "fortran", "cobol", "pascal", "perl", "flash" };
string findText = "spclaa"; 

// do stuff
```

I want result to be **"pascal"**
also if not found give **"sorry, not Found"**

**Updated:**

- this is not homework
- list is about 1000 words so its not easy to sort every word

Comment: If this ain't homework, I don't know what is...

Comment: Do you want partial matches or exact? What about the possibility of repeat matches?

Comment: If you look for examples on how Scrabble solvers work, it's done in a similar way using a dictionary source of words, checking for length, etc.

Comment: @Joel, exact matches and if repeat all of the words

Comment: 1000 words is nothing. Go sort them :)

Comment: If this isn't homework, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one way would be:

1. Create a copy of the array
2. Sort each string alphabetically
3. Sort your search term alphabetically
4. Find the index of the element in the copied array that matches the sorted search term
5. If they match, return the corresponding element from the original (unsorted) array.
6. If they don't match, keep searching.

It's worth noting that it's possible that two words will have the same character content and yet not be equal. For instance, "neo" and "one" have identical characters, but are clearly not the same word.

**Update**

As Paul suggested, this will perform better if you only sort strings that have the same number of characters as the search term.

Comment: I have list of 1000 words, then how can I sort every string.

Comment: The same way you sort one string, only 1000 times (in other words, why does having 1000 strings change anything?)

Comment: @Paul yep. Looks like we posted at the same time.

Comment: "It's worth noting that it's possible that two words will have the same character content and yet not be equal. For instance, "neo" and "one" have identical characters, but are clearly not the same word.". Well, actually it isn't a matter because the original string is jumbled and so it is IMPOSSIBLE to know if the word which the program looks for is the correct one or not. So it isn't correct to say that they're not equal, in this kind of search they ARE equal.

Comment: @AS-CII yes, obviously. That's why it's "worth noting," not included in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like homework

Sort the characters in findText. 
Sort the characters for each word in wordList and make a new list. 
Compare the sorted findText to each sorted word. 
If you get a match, look up the word at the same index in the original wordList.

(you could probably sort the word from wordList just before you compare it)

EDIT: If you really don't want to sort them,

Count how many of each letter there are in findText.

- Iterate through wordList
- For each word,

  - if it is the same length as wordList
  - copy the frequency table for findtext
  - iterate through the word from wordList
  - For each character found, decrement the number in the frequency table if not zero.
  - If you match all letters and end up with all zeros you have a match

Answer (score 1):

One method might be to sort the characters in each string and the comparison string and compare them that way.

```
java becomes aajv
csharp becomes achprs
pascal becomes aaclps
scplaa becomes aaclps
```

Compare the sorted strings for equality and return not found if no matches.

Answer (score 0):

1.Filter the Array List like search string length equal to array list element

2.compare each character in array list element . If you found increment count and remove that character array list element.

3.If count is equal to search string than print array element otherwise element not found

Answer (score 0):

1. List out those strings whose length equals to given string's length.
2. From those filtered list, check the sum of ASCII values of each string with the given string.
3. third and final now match the characters from the filtered list,you will get the jumbled string.